# I don't understand how to use the lexeme function

Tags: haskell, whitespace, lexer, parsec, parser-combinators

From `Text.Parsec.Token`:

```
lexeme p = do { x <- p; whiteSpace; return x }
```

It appears that lexeme takes a parser p and delivers a parser that has the same behavior as p, except that it also skips all the trailing whitespace. Correct?

Then how come the following does not work:

```
constant :: Parser Int
constant = do
    digits <- many1 digit
    return (read digits)

lexConst :: Parser Int
lexConst = lexeme constant
```

The last line results in the following error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `ParsecT
                                String () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Int'
            with actual type `ParsecT s0 u0 m0 a0 -> ParsecT s0 u0 m0 a0'
Expected type: Parser Int
  Actual type: ParsecT s0 u0 m0 a0 -> ParsecT s0 u0 m0 a0
In the return type of a call of `lexeme'
In the expression: lexeme constant
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstood the documentation, the [`lexeme`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html#v%3alexeme) exported from `Text.Parsec.Token` is a field of a [`GenTokenParser s u m`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html#t%3aGenTokenParser), so the type is

```
lexeme :: GenTokenParser s u m -> ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m a
```

and you haven't supplied the `GenTokenParser` argument in `lexeme constant`.

You need to create a `GenTokenParser` from a [`GenLanguageDef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html#t%3aGenLanguageDef) (typically with [`makeTokenParser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html#v%3amakeTokenParser)) first to use its `lexeme` field.

Answer (score 2):

The `lexeme` function is an accessor into a `GenTokenParser` record of parsers generated by `makeTokenParser`, so you need to apply it to such a record to get at it. One common way of doing this is to use record wildcards, e.g.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as Tok

Tok.TokenParser { .. } = Tok.makeTokenParser {- language definition -}
```

This will bring `lexeme` and all the other parsers into scope already applied to the record, so you can use it like you were trying to do.